# Array api call (public)

Tags: jquery, html, api

I’m currently attempting (almost given up) to change the api I use to collect price data for currency trading pairs. However because the new api uses array (after result) everything I’ve tried returns invalid. My current code which works is:

```
function get_price(){
    var price_margin = 0.0010;
 jQuery.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=XRP&tsyms=USD").then(function(data){
    jQuery('#xrp_price').text(function(price){
        return "PRICE " + data["USD"].toFixed(4);
    });

    jQuery('.btn-success').text(function(price){
        return "OVER " + (data["USD"] +     price_margin).toFixed(4);
    });
    jQuery('.btn-danger').text(function(price){
        return "UNDER " + (data["USD"] -     price_margin).toFixed(4);
    });
    setTimeout( get_price, 1000);
    });
```

Changing the url and then + (data["USD"] to Last returns nothing and adding result.last is the same. Am I missing something? The result from the new url is below and I just need the “Last” data to replace “USD”

Thanks for taking the time to look

{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":0.44100000,"Ask":0.44500000,"Last":0.44400000}}

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding and you're just trying to get the "Last" property, it's nested in the 'result' property, so you just do `data.result.Last` and you should be set.

Or `data['result']['Last']` if you prefer that. Remember, the properties are case sensitive, so last is not the same as Last.

Comment: I’d already tried data.Last which obviously hadn’t worked and I’ve just tried data.result.Last now which still doesn’t work :s it’s as if the url I’m using isn’t working  https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=usd-xrp It is public and doesn’t need a key

Comment: And you understood perfectly btw :)

Comment: oh try getJSON instead of get.

Comment: Just to clarify, the data.result.Last is after the .then(function at the top and again after OVER and UNDER?